# Debian upgraded from testing unmet dependencies

Tags: python, debian, stretch

I made a huge mistake - I used the testing repo to upgrade to Python 3.8. I was running Stretch before, then I dist-upgraded to Buster but now I have this issue.

Can I downgrade the package I upgraded somehow to fix updates of (`bc gettext nethogs nmon procps`)?

```
apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  bc gettext nethogs nmon procps
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.


apt install bc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libncurses6 : Depends: libtinfo6 (= 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2) but 6.2-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: "huge mistake"? Do you have also external software installed? If not, wait few days, things should improve (the conflicts seems to arise on the same source package). Else you may use `aptitude`: it will propose you some solution

Comment: Using Docker would be a good way to get around this - it prevents any software changes on the host from interfering with your project(s).

Answer (score 0):

Omg aptitude, totally forget about it
Aptitude was able to downgrade the dependencies, boom working, thank you!